# EE 1x plugin wont parse nested plugin tags

Tags: plugins, expressionengine

I wrote a simple and short expressionengine 1x plugin which works well for what I needed.
It is working fine with the following code:

```
{exp:iv_simple_rss_parser feed="http://imccomunicacion.tumblr.com/rss" strip_tags="yes"}
    Title {title}
    {exp:word_limit total="20"}{description}{/exp:word_limit}
    {link}
{/exp:iv_simple_rss_parser}
```

I needed to limit the {description} var so I wanted to use the word_limit plugin, like you can see. The fact is that all works ok but the description tag is no limited by word_limit.
It seems that EE is not parsing that nested plugin, it just ignores it, like it was not there.
How can I make EE to parse the word_limit plugin when it is inside of my plugin??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the inner-most plugin tag parses first, and at that point, `{description}` doesn't exist yet. You can [reverse the parse order](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order) by adding `parse="inward"` to your outer plugin tag:

```
{exp:iv_simple_rss_parser feed="http://imccomunicacion.tumblr.com/rss" strip_tags="yes" parse="inward"}
    Title {title}
    {exp:word_limit total="20"}{description}{/exp:word_limit}
    {link}
{/exp:iv_simple_rss_parser}
```

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for your answer. So is that all? I should only add that parse="inward" param? Or I should catch it and then make something with it in my plugin? Have in mind I am working on EE 1x

Comment: Nope, just add that to your outer tag and that should do it.